# QT application stay on top on windows 10

Tags: qt, windows-10-desktop, stayontop

`QMainWindow::setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint)` works on all versions of Windows except for Windows 10.

On Windows 10, user can switch desktop using short-cut key: Windows + Tab, and create a new desktop. Thus the user can leave the Qt application.

I want to know how to stay on top on Windows 10.

Comment: What does your app do that you want to revoke the users freedom of switching desktop which is a feature by the OS?

Comment: used by school for exam.

Comment: I think that you should go deeper. You need to disable all applications, including explorer, except yours.

Comment: @xhsoldier: My work machine runs on Windows 8.1. I will check on it once I get to my laptop.